# Apache Django CSRF 403 cookie not set

Tags: django, apache, cookies, django-admin, django-csrf

I am trying to switch over my project from the default django server to Apache and have gotten my website up through a domain name, however I'm getting a csrf 403 message for trying to login to the django authentication system and as an admin through "mysite.com/admin". These were all working on local host before I configured my apache server.

I'm having trouble figuring out what steps to take to debug this as all the suggestions give responses such as setting "CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY" to true and rendering RequestContext etc , all which I've already done to get the CSRF auth working on my localhost.

I've been stuck on this for days and any help would be deeply appreciated.

**Settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',)
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "mysite.UserProfile"
```

**Sample views.py**

```
def login(request):
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
username = request.POST.get('username','')
return render(request,'login.html',c)
```

**Apache config file (000-default.conf)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    Alias /static /var/www/mysite/static/static_root/
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static/static_root>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    Servername mysite.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-path=/var/www:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com
```

All my form actions on my templates have {% csrf_token %}
All my files (besides the config file) are in /var/www and i've given it 755 access.

Comment: Same problem for me and I am looking for a solution. If you found the solution, sharing it with us very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You set `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True`, which means your CSRF cookie will be HTTPS-only (i.e. your browser will only send the cookie over a HTTPS connection).

However, your site is served over HTTP (as evidenced by the fact that there are no SSL directives in your Apache configuration).

---

Either serve your site over HTTPS, or leave `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to its default value (which is `False`).